# FCM allow to only 1000 registration id in one message how we can send notification on 500000 devices in php

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

FCM allow to only 1000 registration id in one message how we can send on 500000 devices in php

Comment: loop 500 times?

Comment: If i am fetching all data in one array but it shows error array memory limit 
Can we use any chunk feature